# Facebook "app" I don't remember adding to profile

Tags: privacy, facebook

Because of all the news about Facebook sharing info, I went to do some scrubbing of my profile. I found that one of the "apps" on my Facebook account was icims, a job candidate tracking and recruiting company. I am looking for a job but in general I wouldn't give employers access to my Facebook while I was applying.

Did I add this and forget about it? Or is there some way that this got snuck onto my Facebook?

Comment: Some services allow you to use your Facebook login versus creating a user account/password, did you do this?  Chances are you allowed this versus it just appearing.  You have to give it permissions to access your account.  I would just suggest removing its permissions.

Comment: Does it matter? How will your behavior change based on the answer? Just remove the app from your Facebook account and get into the habit of checking that tool regularly.

Comment: @DukeSilversJazz I removed the permission. I don't give access to my Facebook. I do to my LinkedIn, but they don't even use the same email address.

Comment: @ale I just found it odd and wanted to find out what happened. Because I know that companies want to look at your social media profiles and so wondered if they snuck on somehow.